# Arba'a Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred four?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Josephus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus) ([*Life*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Life_of_Flavius_Josephus), [chapter 45](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0149%3Awhiston+section%3D45)), there were 204 cities and towns in the Galilee. ([Whiston](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Whiston) [translated](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0150%3Awhiston+section%3D45) this as 240, but that's apparently an error.)

Answer (score 1):

Some give 204 as the number of attendees of the First Zionist Congress, though others differ.

Comment: See also http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/6122#6122.

Answer (score 1):

According to some sources (including [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_Venice#Rise_of_Fascism)), 204 Jews were deported from Venice during the Holocaust.

Answer (score 0):

צדיק    =    204

Comment: Hey! Why'd you remove the answer about 204 _chalakim_?

Comment: it was unappreciated

Comment: Was it? I liked the part of it that answered the question. (The rest of it was good too, but unnecessary.)