# Arba'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred forty?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amalek and Safek both   =   240    .....

Comment: There _is_ a source for this, but I don't recall what it is. Any idea?

Comment: The Chasidishe seforim talk about it. Do not remember which one. I will try to find it.

Answer (score 4):

The Aseres Yemei Teshuva = 240 hours.

Comment: When you consider that Rosh Hashanah starts at sunset and Yom Kippur ends at nightfall, it's actually around 241 hours...

Comment: So answer that for 241

Answer (score 0):

There [are mistakenly claimed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6279) to have been 240 cities and towns in the Galilee during Josephus's time.

Answer (score -1):

Really stretching it, but...

In Gematria, 240 == `אליהו הנביא אליהו הנביא` (sung to the tune used during Seder Pesach...)

Comment: There are many tunes used during the _seder_ (and of course they vary from one person's _seder_ to another's), but I can't think of any offhand that would fit the words _Eliyahu hanavi Eliyahu hanavi_ specifically. Which are you thinking of? (-1, by the way, just because I dislike random _gimatriyaos_ and always downvote them in the mi-yodeya-series.)

Comment: @msh210, umm, "Eliyahu Hanavi"...? Fair point about random gematriyot, though - I usually tend to agree with you, but these are just too much fun...

Comment: Oh, I was unaware of a custom to sing "_Eliyahu Hanavi_" at the _seder_. It's not in any _hagada_ I've seen AFAIR, FWIW.

Comment: Really? Yknow, when you open the door for שפוך חמתך...? Thought this was nearly universal, at least at Ashkenazi / American seders...

Comment: Yes, really and truly. What _hagada_ has it? Do you sing the whole song found in _sidurim_ among the songs for _m'lave malka_?