# Echad Ve'arba'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred forty-one?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The kingdom of the Ten Tribes lasted for 241 years. (It began with their secession following Shlomo's death in [2964 since Creation](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&pgnum=133); the capital, Shomron, was conquered, and its inhabitants exiled, in [3205](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&pgnum=142).)

Answer (score 2):

The Ashkenazim Pasken like the Rama. Rama = 241

Answer (score 2):

In a non-leap year, *Shavout* is the 241st day in the year if *Heshvan* and *Kislev* are both *Haserim* (have 29 days):

*Tishrei* -30 days
*Heshvan*, *Kislev*, *Tevet* - 29 days each
*Shvat* - 30 days
*Adar* - 29 days
*Nisan* - 30 days
*Iyar* - 29 days
*Sivan* - 6 days (*Shavuot* is on the 6th day of *Sivan*)

Answer (score 1):

Gematria for אמר (to say), not to mention that it is 53rd prime number.

Comment: Aww, and you just missed the right week for that...

Comment: @AciD I'm not sure what you mean... and I'm not sure I quite understand the criteria for the voting on these questions...

Comment: I think Avi meant that Parshas Emor (אמר) was two weeks ago. I don't know that there's any "official" rules for what people like and don't like in this series, but in general, it looks like gematriaos aren't well-liked unless there is a source somewhere that indicates their significance.

Answer (score 1):

(To the tune:) [241 are the hours of *t'shuva*.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7425)